# Skype-bin not installable -- 'held broken packages'

Tags: installation, skype

I'm having trouble installing skype. I'm having the same issues as detailed in this thread;

[Installing skype will not work - skype-bin not installable, and 'held broken packages'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213857/installing-skype-will-not-work-skype-bin-not-installable-and-held-broken-pac/232760#232760)

and I am having trouble with this part:

"sudo vi /etc/apt/preferences

and insert the following lines:

Package: *
   Pin: release a=quantal*
   Pin-Priority: 2012

enter :wq to write the file. Pin-Priority must be greater than 1000."

What exactly does "enter :wq" mean? I've tried this numerous times and nothing happens. When I tried to create the file again, it says it may already exist or to delete "etc/apt/preferences.swp" before continuing, but I tried to delete it and it says it can't find it.

Also, when I created the preferences file, it said 'E353 Nothing in register' (it was highlighted in red). Is this standard?

I could use some help if anybody knows anything. Thanks.

Comment: After 8 hours, I finally figured this out. I'm using a Lenovo Ideapad u400. 

"dpkg --print-foreign-architectures";
"dpkg --print-architecture"

If the first comand does not show any output, and the second one gives "amd64" you should try the following commands

"sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386";
"sudo apt-get update"

and then again,

"sudo apt-get install skype"

Answer (score 3):

After 8 hours, I finally figured this out. I'm using a Lenovo Ideapad u400.

```
dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
dpkg --print-architecture
```

If the first command does not show any output, and the second one gives "amd64" you should try the following commands

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skype
```