# Installing Skype on x64 12.10

Tags: 12.10, apt, skype, dependencies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to install Skype on 12.10 64bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215298/unable-to-install-skype-on-12-10-64bit)

So for the past 2 days i've been trying to install skype and none of the solutions i find seem to be working

if i download the file from the skype website the software centre says

```
Wrong architecture 'i386'
```

if i run:

```
sudo apt-get install skype
```

it gives me:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
skype : Depends: skype-bin but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

and i have tried the following commands at some time or other during the search on the internet. (not necessarily after each other)

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get --purge remove skype*
sudo apt-get -f install
```

As for system data:

```
 uname -a; lsb_release -a
```

returns:

```
Linux ubuntu 3.5.0-19-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 13 17:48:01 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.10
Release:    12.10
Codename:   quantal
```