# Can't install Skype In Ubuntu 64 bit

Tags: 64-bit, skype, downloads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to install Skype on 12.10 64bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215298/unable-to-install-skype-on-12-10-64bit)

I can't download skype, is skype currently not available for ubuntu linux 64bit 12.10?

1.dowload skype in official website
2.import canonical repo

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>   skype:Depends: skype-bin but it is no going to be installed

this problem exists,what is skype-bin ?
even i can't download it (sudo apt-get install skype-bin

> E: Package 'skype-bin' has no installation candidate