# **plz help. skype wont install**

Tags: installation, skype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t install Skype In Ubuntu 64 bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226674/cant-install-skype-in-ubuntu-64-bit)

Whenever I try to install it it says,

> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or
>   been moved out of Incoming  The following information may help to
>   resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  skype : Depends:
>   skype-bin but it is not installable  E: Unable to correct problems, 
>   you have held broken packages.

I have tried stuff people told me to do and I still can not get it to work.

Comment: -1 because the title do not follow the rules.
Please read the FAQ before start asking questions. http://askubuntu.com/faq

Answer (score 2):

Your question is the same as the link below. So, go there and see the answers:

- [AskUbuntu - Installing Skype on 12.04 64 bit causes errors
  [closed]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192425/installing-skype-on-12-04-64-bit-causes-errors)

Comment: Once you have enough reputation you will be able to flag these as duplicates. (If you can't do so already).  For now, consider adding the duplicate link as a comment rather than an Answer.

Comment: Ok Ok Fabricator4. didn't knew that. I Don't know if I have that option. Where is it?

Comment: @fabricator4 I received neu notifications: http://i.imgur.com/tG7s4.png

but don't know how to mark as duplicate :\

Comment: Right under the text of the message. "share edit *flag*"

Comment: but the flag option does not have Duplicate options :\