# How to install Skype with Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: software-installation, skype

```
jovan@jovan-HP-ProBook-4540s:~$ sudo apt-get install skype
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies: skype : Depends: skype-bin

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Have you added some PPAs? What does `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` do?

Comment: does nothing read pls:

Comment: jovan@jovan-HP-ProBook-4540s:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: @rolandixor Since you have so much experience would you be so kind and point a direction for me where to search the solution for my issue? Thanks

Comment: @Jovan have you looked at the other question I pointed you to?

Comment: as per @MRseed have you tried `sudo apt-get -f install skype`

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype

Answer (score 132):

## For Ubuntu 13.04 and Onwards ( 13.10 , 14.04 , 14.10 .....)

command line way

Open Terminal & copy paste the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install skype
```

[HELP](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype) [How do I install Skype?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7498/how-do-i-install-skype/287732#287732)

---

> ### GUI WAY

Go To System Settings > Software & Updates

[image]

Then

[image]

Authenticate & Click Close

[image]

Install It From Ubuntu Software Center

[image]

> For Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty (64bit) fix skin issue with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386 sni-qt:i386
```

[image]

Comment: These instructions worked fine for me on Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin), too.

Comment: These instructions work for 13.10 and 14.04. Thank you!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, works in 14.04 64b

Comment: It will work on every Ubuntu version

Comment: You can't install skype on later 64 bit systems without adding i386 architecture. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/215298/unable-to-install-skype-on-64bit-ubuntu

Comment: +1 These instructions also worked for 14.10

Comment: You can also see the Ubuntu Community Page on installing Skype.  I just installed it on my 14.04 64-bit computer.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype

Answer (score 16):

**To install skype:**

You can either do it the easy way by typing this into your Terminal : `sudo apt-get -f install skype` or you can Install skype manually by following these steps:

1. Go to Skype's homepage and download Skype for ubuntu: [Skype Download for Ubuntu](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/)
2. When download is finished, go to the download folder where you downloaded Sype.
3. Right click on the Skype-package you downloaded and click on `open with ubuntu software center`[image]
4. After that this window should open: [image]
5. Now press on install, located in the right corner, and wait until the installation is complete.

Comment: Thanks to all for the input, but it just don't want to work

Comment: Try this: `sudo apt-get -f install skype`

Comment: the versions in the software channel are in my experience more robust.

Comment: For Ubuntu one can download only **precise** or **lucid** compatible Skype...

Comment: it is helpful...

Answer (score 5):

it looks like skype is not in the standard repositories anymore, and also not in the software center. I also had no luck with the downloaded version.

This is what did work: go to settings -> software and updates. now under the 'Other software' tab check the 'canonical partners' sources. after this I did a `sudo apt-get update` and than `sudo apt-get install skype`

Comment: Same all same all

Answer (score 1):

egh, finally skype got update! (bellow is how to manually update skype)

```
sudo apt-get remove skype
```

then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install skype
```

Enjoy Skype on Ubuntu ^-^

In case `sudo apt-get install skype` does not work or gives you an error even though you ran: `sudo apt-get update`, then go to http://skype.com and download it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough reputation to give a comment but upvoted user172139's answer since that's the solution that fixed the problem described (same problem I had:

Change the download server in the **Ubuntu Software Center** > **Software Sources** from **your country** (I'm currently in Serbia, but had this problem as well when I lived in Denmark) to the **Main Server**.

When doing `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` after this I had bunch of previously unavailable updates and `sudo apt-get install skype` worked like a charm. Now I have Skype installed and working fine!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to enable Partners software source in Software Center. Then just `apt-get update` then `apt-get install skype`. Works like expected to work. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Skype is presently a 32-bit linux application (as of 2014). Thus to get skype 32-bit to install on 64-bit ubuntu you may need to type the following first:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```

THEN TYPE:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skype
```

Comment: The method you gave is obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install skypeforlinux
```

Run this to install [Skype for Linux Alpha](https://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Skype-for-Linux-Alpha-and-calling-on-Chrome-amp-Chromebooks/td-p/4434299).

> This is the new version of Skype for Linux, a brand new client using
>   WebRTC, the launch of which ensures Microsoft can continue to support
>   Linux users in the years to come.
>
> As you may have guessed by the name, Skype for Linux Alpha is not a
>   fully functioning Skype client as of yet. Once you’ve downloaded the
>   app, you’ll notice that it’s very different to the Skype for Linux
>   client you use today. For example, you’ll be using the latest, fastest
>   and most responsive Skype UI, so you can share files, photos, videos
>   and a whole new range of new emoticons with your friends.

Basically Microsoft has put Skype into a web renderer and released it like an application. Just like [Ghetto Skype](https://github.com/stanfieldr/ghetto-skype) but coming officially from Microsoft.

Cons

- Video calls do not work and you have to initiate the audio call (if
  they call you, it wants you to install plugin).

Answer (score -2):

Had same problem after I have switched to Ubuntu. 
To solve this, go to "software and updates" and then, on Ubuntu Software tab, change "Download from: #your country# (guess its my region/country)" and change it to "Main Server".
Run "apt-get upgrade" and "apt-get update". After "that apt-get install skype" and it should be just fine.

Hope this will solve it.

Regards,

Comment: The servers have the same content regardless of location. The issue is in enabling the partner repository.

Answer (score -2):

Guyz,

TRY this, installed in my machine thorugh this command

**sudo apt-get -f install skype**

Comment: @guntbert `apt-get -f install skype` does not "force install". I think what you're referring to is `--force-yes`. The option mentioned in the answer basically tells Ubuntu that "`skype` is the package that will fix the dependency issues". But it's a wrong answer though, because `skype` **is** the package we're trying to install in the first place.