# 64 bit - Ubuntu 13.04 Skype 4.2 can not install

Tags: installation, 64-bit, skype

I've been trying to download and install skype 4.2 on my PC for a long time, I have attempted many times but I have failed.
The description of my computer is the following:

- Dual Booting with Windows 8 (32 bit)
- Installed Ubuntu 13.04 (64-bit) with Wubi
- Installed skype app and desktop application for windows
- I have installed all updates and Ubuntu seems to run smoothly and sexy (as usual).

I have tried to install it from the skype website (http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/), not knowing which distribution to choose, I chose the "Ubuntu 12.04 (multiarch)" Distribution. After downloading I get the "skype-ubuntu-lucid_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb" package on my downloads folder. After double-clicking it I get the following message from the Ubuntu Software Center: "Wrong Architecture 'i386'"
withtout further explanation.

Then I try the "Ubuntu 10.04 (32-bit)" distribution... same results.
Then I try the "Dynamic" distribution... get a "skype-4.2.0.11.tar.bz2"And I get the following read me file:

> Skype for Linux 4.2 README
>
> ## INSTALLATION
>
> If you are using one of the distribution-specific packages, simply run the
>   "skype" executable.  KDE users should find a launcher for Skype in their
>   Internet menu if Skype has been installed through one of these packages.
>
> If you are using the dynamic and statically linked generic versions, you
>   will need to choose a path for Skype to exist in.  We recommend copying the
>   skype binary to /usr/bin and installing sounds/, lang/ and avatars/ into
>   the /usr/share/skype directory.

Since I don't have a lot of experience with Linux, I haven't accepted tux as my lord and saviour, neither I have been Bourne Again (get it? Bourne Again? anyone? no? okay.), I just know the basic commands. Even though I know them, I couldn't successfully, do what the README file instructed me to do. I tried 'cp' and 'mv' but I miserably failed to do so.

```
$ cp skype-4.2.0.11.tar.bz2 /usr/bin
```

I don't think I am doing it correctly because I get the following output:

```
cp: cannot stat ‘skype-4.2.0.11.tar.bz2’: No such file or directory
```

I assumed that that wasn't actually the binary file so I just tried inputting the following:

```
$ cp skype /usr/bin
```

the file that was in the tar.bz2 with no other description or extension just "skype". and it failed

I am assuming you think I am either a troll, an ignoramus, or just had a sucky teacher... what am I doing wrong? Do I specify where the file is? How do you install the Dynamic distribution?

Anyway, I tried Googling it and I found the following: 
[How to install Skype with Ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293693/how-to-install-skype-with-13-04)
I LITERALLY tried every single thing, every input and every suggestion. Nothing worked, most inputs gave me the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype : Depends: skype-bin but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

:(
I tried the following suggested from: 
http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-ringtail-skype.html

```
chalgafe@ubuntu:~$ sudo dpkg -i --force-architecture skype-ubuntu-
```

this was the input:

```
lucid_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb
dpkg: error processing skype-ubuntu-lucid_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 skype-ubuntu-lucid_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb
```

I believe that's what he meant with the asterisk right? to put our corresponding distributions?

anyway, it didn't work. What am I doing incorrectly? What can I do?

---

Other unnecessary details
(please, don't let this affect your answer by straying away from the problem)

- Skype is the only reason I am still using windows 8
- On other forums, people that had windows 8 and skype app for it, couldn't install it either. Is there a correlation?
- There s no other way of accessing skype unfortunately.

Comment: really nice formatting though.

Comment: Please try the answers to the master question (linked at the top of your question) and let us know how that goes. It would be best if you started from a fresh install too.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it. If it doesn't solve, I will comment back

Comment: I did try everything from the link provided. Nothing worked. Nothing. I still get the same "Wrong architecture" and I can't force it. I tried dpkg from Terminal but didn't work. It says it has "Unmet dependencies" or "dpkg: error processing /home/chalgafe/Downloads/skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb (--install):
 package architecture (i386) does not match system (amd64)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /home/chalgafe/Downloads/skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb" The problem is different, that answers to those questions focus mainly on how add repositories. that is not it.

Comment: Is it because I installed Ubuntu with Wubi?