# skype has a problem with audio playback

Tags: sound, skype, microphone

I know there are a few threads started on this question, but no one seems to be offering answers to them, so I thought I would try my luck.

Skype is giving me the message "problem with audio playback" when I installed it on my ubuntu 13.10 (using lenovo u430, touch screen).  It will not let me make or receive calls.  I went through the steps [provided through the community help docs for troubleshooting Skype](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SkypeTroubleshooting) and nothing worked.  It's a new computer, and the microphone is working fine, from all I've been able to tell.

Please help!!

Comment: _"..but no one seems to be offering answers..."_ in such case what you should do is start a [bounty](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) on that question rather than posting a duplicate Q.. for that privilege you'll need to have 75 AU [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation)..

Comment: Ok, sorry, I didn't know. I'm new to the community.

Comment: hope someone soon posts a fix that helps you.. keep following.. and btw, welcome to AU..

Answer (score 0):

[Original thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293693/how-to-install-skype-with-13-04)

So, seems that you need to install this way (line by line):

**Don't forget to uninstall old existing skype from your pc!**

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install skype
```

This method worked for me. I remember I downloaded skype from skype.com deb package, installed, and had many problems similar to yours. After installing via terminal using repositories, I have 100% luck. Hope that helps ;)