# Skype issue with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, skype

For some days now I have a problem with Skype. It just didn't launch at all, even when I was logged in. So I removed it and now I want to install it again but, after having followed all the steps, when I put in the Terminal "**sudo apt-get install skype**", first I get

- **no talloc stackframe at ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4864, leaking memory**

and after that

- **Unable to locate package skype**

I tried to find out something but I can't. Can somebody help, please?

---

**15/07: Finally I have skype. I'm sharing in case anyone has the same problem. It's just that I prefer to install via Terminal, but as it was not possible, I just downloaded the package from skype.com and installed it via the Software centre.**

Comment: Please have a look at [this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14089/please-can-people-format-code-properly) and [this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/993/how-much-editing-is-fine-removing-hi-thanks-etc); I won't insist on editing your post, but please reformat it yourself according to those guidelines, because it's common opinion that code is better formatted using backticks or indentation and that the questions are better intelligible without salutations and greetings at the start / at the end.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install Skype with Ubuntu 13.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/293693/how-to-install-skype-with-ubuntu-13-04)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Skype?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7498/how-do-i-install-skype)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in `libpam-smbpass`: [bug report on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1257186)

Upgrade `libpam-smbpass` to the latest version using this command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libpam-smbpass
```

If the bug breaks the capability of running this command as well, download the package from packages.ubuntu.com and install it manually: [`libpam-smbpass` on packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libpam-smbpass).