# What are the biggest disadvantages of using a 64bit version of linux over a 32bit and vice-versa

Tags: wine, 64-bit, 32-bit, architecture

I've been using Ubuntu 12.10 for some time now, but I am very limited when it comes to installing some software such as wine that won't run on a 64bit. I want to know what are the biggest disadvantages/advantages of both the 32 and 64 bit. Will it be worth switching to a 32bit? If using a 32bit will my programs still work?

Will this command change completely the architecture from 64 to 32bit, or will it just add support to 32bit while keeping the 64bit?

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-are-the-differences-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose

Answer (score 0):

> Will this command change completely the architecture from 64 to 32bit, or will it just add support to 32bit while keeping the 64bit?

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Some packages which are related to particular software are available only in 32bit form. Software manufacturers may fail to create 64 bit packages for this kind of applications. To install 32 bit packages on 64 bit Ubuntu systems, you have to add the above command.(`sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`). It adds 32 bit architecture to 64 bit systems which in turn helps to install packages which are in 32 bit form.

No, the above command won't change completely the system architecture from 64 to 32bit, it adds support to install 32 bit packages on 64 bit systems.

One best example is, [Skype](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215298/unable-to-install-skype-on-64bit-ubuntu). You can install skype easily on 32 bit systems but for 64 bit systems you have to add  i386 architecture.Because there isn't any 64 bit form of Skype.