# Can't install skype in 14.04 64-bit

Tags: dpkg, skype

I have a problem with installing skype in my fresh new Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit, Using Ubuntu Software Center

**Solution**: In Software & Updates set Download from: Main Server

Download skype and install it through the Terminal

```
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of skype:  skype
    depends on libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0).  skype depends on libqtwebkit4 (>=
    2.2~2011week36).
```

Install through the Terminal

```
 sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
 sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://archive.canonical.com/ trusty partner' >>/etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list"    
 sudo apt-get update          
 sudo apt-get install skype
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype : Depends: skype-bin
```

Result from apt-cache policy skype:

```
skype:
  Installed: 4.2.0.11-0ubuntu0.12.04.2
  Candidate: 4.2.0.11-0ubuntu0.12.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 4.2.0.11-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 0
        500 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty/partner amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.canonical.com/ trusty/partner amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Result from sudo apt-get check:

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>   state information... Done

Result from apt-cache policy 'skype*:*':

```
skype:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.2.0.11-0ubuntu0.12.04.2
  Version table:
     4.2.0.11-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 0
        500 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty/partner amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.canonical.com/ trusty/partner amd64 Packages
skype4pidgin:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
skype-mid:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
pidgin-skype-dbg:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 20130613+svn660+dfsg-1
  Version table:
     20130613+svn660+dfsg-1 0
        500 http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
skype-bin:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
skype-common:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
```

Result from cat /var/lib/dpkg/arch:

```
amd64
i386
```

Result from sudo apt-get update

```
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease                              
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                          
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg                   
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release                                
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release                                
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                 
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Sources                        
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages               
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner amd64 Packages       
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner i386 Packages        
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease               
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner amd64 Packages       
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner i386 Packages        
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease             
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US           
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US           
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease              
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                     
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg [933 B]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release [58.5 kB]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en                                                                               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en                                                                               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                                                                                 
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources [1,712 B]                                                                        
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources [14 B]                                                                     
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [648 B]                                                                      
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources [1,790 B]                                                                  
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [2,966 B]                                                                 
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [14 B]                                                              
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1,602 B]                                                             
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [6,362 B]                                                          
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [2,998 B]                                                                 
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages [14 B]                                                              
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [1,601 B]                                                             
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [6,386 B]                                                           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en                                                                             
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en                                                                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en                                                                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en                                                                         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources                                                                                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources                                                                            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources                                                                              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources                                                                            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages                                                                           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages                                                                     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages                                                                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages                                                                     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages                                                                            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages                                                                      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages                                                                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages                                                                      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en                                                                           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en                                                                     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en                                                                     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en                                                                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources                                                                                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources                                                                             
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources                                                                               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources                                                                             
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages                                                                            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages                                                                      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages                                                                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages                                                                      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages                                                                             
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages                                                                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en_US
```

Comment: Did you install the i386 libraries?  Skype is a 32 bit program.

Comment: No, I didn't, how to do that?

Comment: You don't have to. Installing skype from software center should install everything you need.

Comment: skype worked on my 14.04 updated from 12.04, but the skype package is not yet present in the trusty package offerings, so maybe you have to wait until the Final release, Apr 26th ?

Comment: Yeah, whenever i try do install it from the software center i get this message right on the place of the install button:
Cannot install 'libqtgui4:i386'
what next? how can i install the i386 library on the new 14.04.... With every new realease a lot of new problems ....... Great.

Comment: did you add `i386` architecture? Please see http://askubuntu.com/a/383338/202806

Comment: Yes, I did, I forgot to write it.

Comment: post the output of `apt-cache policy skype`

Comment: @AvinashRaj I updated my question

Comment: oh god. First remove any skype version you have downloaded `sudo apt-get remove 'skype*'` then paste the output of `sudo apt-get check` and `sudo dkpg -C`. Also include the output of `apt-cache policy 'skype*:*'`

Comment: @Braiam I updated my question.

Comment: the output of `apt-cache policy 'skype*:*'` lacks several things. Please review that you are not using the old output.

Comment: post the output of `cat /var/lib/dpkg/arch`

Comment: @Braiam sorry the output is right but I hadn't showed all of it. Now I've just updated the output.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I put the output

Comment: choose best server from software and updates and then try again.Did you try http://askubuntu.com/questions/450101/cant-install-skype-in-14-04-64-bit#comment592002_450101 ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I tried as you can see from my approach with installing through the Terminal.

Comment: how did you solve your problem?

Comment: Can you update the output after you have run `sudo apt-get update`? Apparently you have run it.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I solved the problem after setting the different server for updates (Main server).

Comment: @Braiam you meant the whole output from 'sudo apt-get update'?

Comment: Yeah, that would be useful. Also after that update the output of apt-cache.

Comment: @Braiam it is done.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, the solution is to download the multiarch version skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.13-1_i386 (http://www.skype.com/pt/download-skype/skype-for-linux/downloading/?type=ubuntu64)

To install: **right click > Open with Ubuntu Software Center > Install**

Hope this helps you.

Comment: No, this don't fix my problem, I get the following: "Cannot install libqtgui4:i386"