# Unable to install Skype in

Tags: apt

Im using 64bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in hp Compaq laptop, and when im trying to install using Ubuntu Software Center Im getting following error

```
sudo apt-get install skype
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype : Depends: skype-bin but it is not installable
         Conflicts: skype:i386 but 4.3.0.37-1 is to be installed
 skype:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.3.6-6~) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-dbus:i386 (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-network:i386 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-xml:i386 (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqtgui4:i386 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqtwebkit4:i386 (>= 2.2~2011week36) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libx11-6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libxext6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libxss1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libxv1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libssl1.0.0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libpulse0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libasound2-plugins:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: sni-qt:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Conflicts: skype but 4.3.0.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/215298/unable-to-install-skype-on-64bit-ubuntu

Comment: I tried all the solutions in  askubuntu.com/questions/215298/… but still I could not install skype successfully...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install Skype 4.3?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/488053/how-to-install-skype-4-3)

Comment: Im sorry, This answer also didnt work

Comment: What's the output of `sudo apt-get check` and `apt-cache policy skype-bin skype:i386 libc6:i386`.

Comment: Here is the out put of the above commands
~$ sudo apt-get check
[sudo] password for meenakshi: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

Comment: ~$ apt-cache policy skype-bin skype:i386 libc6:i386
skype-bin:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
skype:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
     4.3.0.37-1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libc6:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.19-0ubuntu6.3
  Version table:
     2.19-0ubuntu6.3 0
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main i386 Packages
     2.19-0ubuntu6 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages

Answer (score 2):

Run these commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
$ sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install skype
```

Comment: Hi James, Thanks for your help. I tried your solution but i got following message

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype : Depends: skype-bin but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Update your question with the output of each line.  Advise me when you have.  I can then advise you of where you're going wrong.

Comment: I don't understand why downvote to my answer as not being useful.  If anyone would look at the the question they will see the system telling the user to use the "sudo apt-get install -f" to clear up the broken packages.  The `i386 architecture` is crucial for `Skype dependencies`.  You have to also install the `canonical partners support` for your Ubuntu version, then update and install skype.  I have been installing skype on Ubuntu for 4 years on numerous machines for friends and family.  I don't know if it's possible without the provided steps. Stop being mean to users trying to contribute.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes

Comment: @ChandrashekharRachakonda You're very welcome.  Most likely, as with many friends and clients, this should resolve your issue.  If it doesn't, let me know and I'll check to see what component may be missing.  Also, if you're issue is resolved, please mark the answer as accepted.  This will help others to easier find a resolution that works.