# How to install Skype

Tags: 14.04, skype

I have downloaded Skype for Ubuntu from official website http://www.skype.com/en/ 
When I try to open it, file automatically running trough "Ubuntu Software Center". After clicking on install process is running and then after nothing is getting changed. I have tried to install trough terminal but still I don't see any change. No software was installed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to install Skype on 64bit Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/215298/unable-to-install-skype-on-64bit-ubuntu)

Comment: Hit `Super Key` and type `Skype`. To make sure that you have installed it or not?

Answer (score 1):

Use can **install skype** from your `terminal` via

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install skype
```

Comment: I have already tried this but nothing changed and nothing happened after progress in terminal finished