# Just recentlygot Ubuntu and have no idea what to do

Tags: 15.04

Assume I have absolutely no idea what im doing,Im trying to just get used to and set up some basic things using this OS, tried to install Java and couldnt even manage that.

If possible, id like to be able to play League of Legends, install Skype and Java.

Comment: I'm going to write up an answer for you about installing these.

Comment: Alright, thank you, sorry for my ignorance, it just feels better to get live-ish help versus using a tutorial.

Comment: Just posted my answer. Hope it helps

Comment: So i got to the adobe air, and got this message

Executing w_do_call adobeair
Executing load_adobeair
Downloading http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/win/download/4.0/AdobeAIRInstaller.exe to /home/dj/.cache/winetricks/adobeair
--2015-08-28 17:48:49--  http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/win/download/4.0/AdobeAIRInstaller.exe
Resolving airdownload.adobe.com (airdownload.adobe.com)... 23.62.7.138, 23.62.7.154
Connecting to airdownload.adobe.com (airdownload.adobe.com)|23.62.7.138|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2015-08-28 17:48:49 ERROR 404: Not Found.

Comment: I don't see anything.

Comment: Please 1 question per topic and do not use comments to post information, instead edit the question.

Comment: @DarellPeltJr. Comment on my answer next time. You should also be able to go without Adobe Air, but if not I'll get the download and give instructions.

Answer (score 2):

- Skype for Ubuntu can be downloaded from:
  http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/downloading/?type=ubuntu64.
  That'll download a `DEB` file, which you can just open to install.

  Also, you might want to refer to these Ask Ubuntu questions, which
  give an alternative to just downloading the `DEB`. You'll also get
  updates more easily this way. You just have to use the terminal.
  [Unable to install Skype on 64bit Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215298/unable-to-install-skype-on-64bit-ubuntu)
  [How do I install Skype?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7498/how-do-i-install-skype)
- Java is also pretty easy. Refer to this Ask Ubuntu question to learn
  how to get it:
  [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java)
- League of Legends is a bit of a complicated procedure. You first need
  to install `Wine`, a program that lets you run certain Windows
  programs on Linux. To install it:

  1. Open a terminal by hitting
     <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
  2. type this: `sudo apt-get install wine`, put in your password and let it run.

     2a. You may have to add a repository to install Wine. Do it by running these two commands:
     `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa` and
     `sudo apt-get update`.
  3. After Wine is installed, you'll need some extras (run these as
     commands in the terminal, no `sudo` needed):
     `winetricks vcrun2005`
     `winetricks ie8`
     `winetricks wininet`
     `winetricks d3dx9`
     `winetricks corefonts`
     `winetricks adobeair`
     `winecfg`

  Once that's done you can then go on to installing LoL.

  1. Download the Windows installer from https://signup.leagueoflegends.com/en/signup/redownload. Choose your
     language and such.
  2. Once it downloads, you need to run it with Wine. To do this, you'll need to run `wine /path/to/exe` in the terminal.
     The command should look something like:
     `wine /home/your_username/Downloads/LeagueofLegends_NA_Installer_9_15_2014.exe`.

     **Remember to change the `your_username` to your actual username (case-sensitive).**
  3. The installer should run through and you should see a shortcut to LoL on your desktop. If it isn't there, you should be able to find the executable under
     `/home/your_username/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Program\ Files/`.
     Use a terminal to run
     `nautilus /home/your_username/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Program\ Files/`.
     This will
     open the file browser to the location of the LoL install folder. Find
     it in here, go into it and double-click the EXE to run the program
     there.

     Further reading:
     http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=2957372
- That should cover everything. If there's something I missed or something you need help with in these steps, comment and tell me. I'll do my best to help.